# Empty <li> appears after every normal <li>

Tags: php, html, random, listitem, unordered

I'm creating an unordered list with PHP. The list is outputting fine, just as expected. However, after every list item, an extra, empty list item appears. I can't figure out why this is happening. There's really nothing else to explain or elaborate on.

Here's the code:

```
    echo '      <div><ul>';
    $i=0;
    while($i<$length && $i<$amount) {
        do {
            $id = rand(0, $amount-1);
        } while(($priority[$id] > $cur_prior || $used[$id]));

        do { $cur_prior++; } while(!in_array($cur_prior, $priority) && $cur_prior <= max($priority));

        if(!$used[$id]) {
            $cur_views = $views[$id]+1;
            $cur_id = $ids[$id];
            mysql_query("   UPDATE table SET views = '$cur_views'
                            WHERE id = '$cur_id'")
                or die('Database error.');

            $used[$id] = true;

            echo '  <li><a href="'.$ids[$id]).'/'.$url[$id].'" target="_blank">
                        <img src="'.$img['main']['folder'].$img[$id].'?'.time().'" alt="'.$name[$id].'" title="'.$name[$id].'">
                    </a><li>';

            $i++;
        }
    }
    echo '      </ul></div>';
```

Hope someone can help, thanks :)

Comment: Seems like you forgot your closing `<li>` next to the closing `</a>`.

Comment: that is often because of missing a closing `<li>`. Just a simple mistake in the HTML, can happen, nothing special to ask about, you will get used to this bug and fix it by using a HTML validator. Install a browser addon for that, it tells you exactly about these and other errors in no time (and often has some more helpful tips at hand so you even learn on the go).

Comment: Thanks :) Silly I missed this little mistake. I just checked it with firebug and it displayed valid html, so I didn't think to check the li tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your echo statement doesn't close `li`, it creates a new `li`

Try this instead:

```
echo '  <li><a href="'.ids[$id]).'/'.$aurl[$id].'" target="_blank">
    <img src="'.$img['main']['folder'].$img[$id].'?'.time().'" alt="'.$name[$id].'" title="'.$name[$id].'">
    </a></li>'; // fixed this line
```

Comment: Oh my, how silly. Thanks, PaulProgrammer and Memolition! ^^

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on the

echo

```
echo '  <li><a href="'.ids[$id]).'/'.$aurl[$id].'" target="_blank">
                    <img src="'.$img['main']['folder'].$img[$id].'?'.time().'" alt="'.$name[$id].'" title="'.$name[$id].'">
                </a><li>';
```

you don't close the `<li>` you have to close it `</li>`